# Is it possible to find the expression of the antiderivative $\int \frac{dx}{\cosh(x)+\sqrt{\cosh(2x)}}$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I have been asked to express the integral $$\int \frac{dx}{\cosh(x)+\sqrt{\cosh(2x)}}$$

I thought about the substitution $$t=e^x$$

but it gave me a more complicate function. So, any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: With that substitution, you should get: $$\int \frac{2\,dt}{t^2+1+\sqrt{2(t^4+1)}}$$ Just for completeness. Not sure if that is harder or easier.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, exactly but then ?

Comment: If I had an answer, I’d have posted more help. Since you didn’t show your work, I did the substitution you recommended, because I’m not convinced it is actually harder from here.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews If it is possible, just give the next substitution $ t=?$.

Comment: As I said, if I had an answer...

Comment: Sorry, great respect !

Comment: [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F%28t%5E2+%2B+1+%2B+sqrt%282%29+sqrt%28t%5E4+%2B+1%29%29+dt) gives an answer in terms of the first and second elliptic integrals with parameter $m = k^2$.

Comment: You can try the analogous integral with "cosine" and transform it to hyperbolic functions, if it does seems easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $\cosh(x)=t$ we end with
$$I=\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^2-1}  \left(t+\sqrt{2 t^2-1}\right)}$$ for which a CAS gives
$$I=\frac{-2 t^3+\sqrt{2 t^2-1}+\sqrt{2-4 t^2} \sqrt{1-t^2} \left(F\left(\sin
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2} t\right)|\frac{1}{2}\right)-E\left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}
   t\right)|\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)+t}{  \sqrt{(t^2-1)(2 t^2-1)}}$$ Back to $x$
$$I=\text{csch}(x)-\sqrt{\cosh (2 x)} \coth (x)-i \left(F(i x|2)+E(i x|2)\right)$$